# PowerShell PnP sort SharePoint choice column failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

This code worked for about last 2 months, then is now failing:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://myco.sharepoint.com/sites/sandbox"; -UseWebLogin

$listsToAdd = @("Structure Reqs","Perm Mods")

ForEach ($listToAdd in $listsToAdd)
{
$field = Get-PnPField -List $listToAdd -Identity "MyTargetColumn"
$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$fieldChoice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldChoice]).Invoke($ctx,$field)

$ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
Invoke-PnPQuery

$choices = $fieldChoice.Choices
$choices += "MyNewValue".ToUpper()

$fieldChoice.Choices = $choices | Sort-Object

$fieldChoice.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
Invoke-PnPQuery
}
```

*** Error message is:

```
Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object does not match target type."
At line:14 char:1
+ $fieldChoice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException


Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At line:16 char:1
+ $ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest


The property 'Choices' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:22 char:1
+ $fieldChoice.Choices = $choices | Sort-Object
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound


You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:1
+ $fieldChoice.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object does not match target type."
At line:14 char:1
+ $fieldChoice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException


Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At line:16 char:1
+ $ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest


The property 'Choices' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:22 char:1
+ $fieldChoice.Choices = $choices | Sort-Object
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound


You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:1
+ $fieldChoice.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you...looks like I had to delete SharePoint GAC, restart, and re-install PnP Online and it started working.

Comment: Great to hear it's starting to be working in your side, you can accept this as answer so that it could also help others in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the PnP PowerShell in my side:

```
$creds = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com",(ConvertTo-SecureString "yourpassword" -AsPlainText -Force))
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Credentials $creds
 
$listsToAdd = @("MyList2","MyList3")

ForEach ($listToAdd in $listsToAdd)
{
    $field = Get-PnPField -List $listToAdd -Identity "MyTargetColumn"
    $ctx = Get-PnPContext

    $fieldChoice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldChoice]).Invoke($ctx,$field)

    $ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
    Invoke-PnPQuery

    $choices = $fieldChoice.Choices
    $choices += "MyNewValue".ToUpper()

    $fieldChoice.Choices = $choices | Sort-Object

    $fieldChoice.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
    Invoke-PnPQuery
}
```

It's working to add the new option and sort order:

[image]

I'm using the latest PnP version.